# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 - Missing Reference to System.Net / Unable to FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I'm new to ASP.NET 5 and I'm having issues testing a FTP process. I've tried various solutions such as adding dependencies to both frameworks in the `project.json` file, but I have a feeling that I'm missing something critical. I can't seem to find a decent FTP example using ASP.NET 5 and if you google for one you'll find and endless sea of 'unable to publish via FTP' issues.

My ultimate goal is to take a file, specifically a database backup, from a specified location on disk and FTP it to a FTP server I've setup on an internal network.

Although I've been doing a lot of testing with the dependencies, here is what my `project.json` currently looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://localhost:5000",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
```

Here is a sample of the C# code. The issue appears on the first line:

```
    public class FileTransfer
    {
        public static void TestFTP()
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://MY_FTP_ADDRESS");
```

If I hover over the `FtpWebRequest`, I see a PopUp that indicates that `FtpWebRequest` is available in DNX 4.5.1, but unavailable in DNX Core 5.0, which is why I started down the path of solutions regarding dependencies in the `project.json` file. If I try to build the solution, the following error occurs:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'FtpWebRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) dba_tools.DNX Core 5.0

Does anyone have any viable solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the following from your project.json file.

```
,
"dnxcore50": {
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

It won't let you run the code since it's not supported in ASP.NET Core. If you remove dnxcore50 and then run it, it should load up just fine since what you're trying to do is supported by the full .NET Framework.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. I assumed if the dnxcore50 dependencies were empty everything would compile and work just fine. That was a bad assumption. I appreciate your help!